# My SELECT query doesn't return any values but only show an empty grid

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to SQL programming and having a problem with a query that doesn't return the values but only an empty query with status and city but no values.

S has the following attributes: sNo, sName, status, city
SP has the following attributes:sNo, pNo, qty,

Can anyone explain to me why the values don't come up?

```
SELECT S.status, S.city
FROM S, SP
WHERE S.sNo='Paris' AND SP.sNo=S.sNo;
```

Comment: Are  you comparing sNo with city?

Comment: Obviously without seeing your data it's impossible to say for certain but I'd guess that your sNo column maybe contains numbers and not city names. Also you should learn how to use proper INNER JOIN syntax instead of the old fashioned practice of separating the table names with commas

Comment: On a side note: Don't use comma-separated joins. If you are being taught to do so by a book, tutorial or class, then quit it. Use proper ANSI joins instead. But why are you joining SP at all? You are neither using it in the select clause nor in the where clause. If you want to ensure that an SP record exists for an S row, then use `IN` or `EXISTS` instead of a join.

Answer (score 3):

First, if you are learning SQL, you should be learning SQL correctly.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

So, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT S.status, S.city
FROM S JOIN
     SP
     ON SP.sNo = S.sNo
WHERE S.sNo = 'Paris' ;
```

Why does this return no results?  Here are some reasons:

- No rows in `S` and `SP` share the same city.
- `S.sNo` never has the value `'Paris'`.
- One or the other table has no rows (this is a subset of the first reason, but worth highlighting).

In this case, the most likely reason is the `sNo` never has the value `'Paris'`.  You have not provided any data, so I can only speculate that you intend:

```
SELECT S.status, S.city
FROM S JOIN
     SP
     ON SP.sNo = S.sNo
WHERE S.city = 'Paris' ;
```

But that would make sense.

One thing is suspicious.  I would expect a key column called `sNo` to be numeric.  In most databases, a comparison to a string (such as `'Paris'`) would return a type conversion error.  MySQL does implicit conversion.  So, if `sNo` is a number, then the comparison is interpreted as `sNo = 0` -- and that could actually return rows if the condition were true.

Comment: Very good feedback, Gordon - thanks a lot!
Regarding the use of the comma in the FROM-clause, I have been taught to do it through a course book from Elmasri & Navathe but has seen tutorials where a join is used instead - that confused me.
But you are sure right that sNo is numeric, I really must have been tired.

Comment: @Triber . . . There are many books (including my own) that would teach you proper SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

in where clause   `s.city ='paris'`

**query**

```
  SELECT S.status, S.city
    FROM S, SP
    WHERE S.city ='Paris' AND SP.sNo=S.sNo;
```

Comment: Well that is obvious now that you write it :D I need to pay more attention to the attributes! Thanks a lot!